# How to dynamically create and inject services in ASP.NET 5?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I'm in a situation where the classic functionality of vnext's DI container is not enough to provide me with the correct functionality. Let's say I have a DataService that gets data from a database like this:

```
public class DataService : IDataService, IDisposable {
  public List<MyObject> GetMyObjects() 
  {
    // do something to fetch the data...
    return myObjects;
  }
}
```

I can then register this service in the DI container during the configuration phase in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
  services.AddScoped(typeof(IDataService), typeof(DataService));
}
```

This ensures the correct lifecylce of the service (one per request scope), however, I need the service to access a different database when a different request is made. For simplicity reasons, let's say the following scenario applies:

- when a request to my Web API is made, the `DataService` will access the currently logged in user, which contains a claim called `Database` which contains the information which database to use.
- the `DataService` is then instantiated with the correct database connection.

In order to get the second step to work, I have created a constructor for the DataService like this:

```
public DataService(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) 
{
   // get the information from HttpContext
   var currentUser = accessor.HttpContext.User;
   var databaseClaim = currentUser.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals("Database"));

   if (databaseClaim != null) 
   {
      var databaseId = databaseClaim.Value;
      // and use this information to create the correct database connection
      this.database = new Database(databaseId);
   }
}
```

By using the currently logged in user and his claims, I can ensure that my own authentication middleware takes care of providing the necessary information to prevent attackers from trying to access the wrong database.

Of course adding the `IDisposable` implementation is required to cleanup any database connections (and gets called correctly using the scope lifecycle).

I can then inject the `DataService` into a controller like this

```
public MyController : Controller 
{
   private IDataService dataService;
   public MyController(IDataService dataService) 
   {
     this.dataService = dataService;
   }
}
```

This all works fine so far.
My questions now are:

1. Is there another way to create the instance other than using the constructor of the `DataService`? Maybe accessing the object the `IServiceCollection` provides in a different place other than during the configration phase which runs only once? Maybe using my own OWIN middleware?
2. Is this method really safe? Could two requests made at the same time accidentally end up with the `DataService`intended for the other request and therefore end up giving out the wrong data?

Comment: What about creating a factory that gives you the specific DB instance that you need depending on certain parameters?

Comment: Such a factory already exists in my project and is used by my DataService. I have omitted it here to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is fine.

> Is there another way to create the instance other than using the constructor of the DataService? Maybe accessing the object the IServiceCollection provides in a different place other than during the configration phase which runs only once? Maybe using my own OWIN middleware?

Not really. You can use delegate registration but it's the same problem.

> Is this method really safe?

Yes

> Could two requests made at the same time accidentally end up with the DataServiceintended for the other request and therefore end up giving out the wrong data?

Nope. The IHttpContextAcessor uses AsyncLocal (http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html) to provide access to the "current" http context.